# Anti-matching against an infinite family of <!before> patterns in Raku

Tags: grammar, raku

I am trying to avoid matching whitespace at the end of a string while still matching whitespace in the middle of words.

Here is an example of a regex that matches underscores within `x` but does not match up to three trailing underscores.

```
say 'x_x___x________' ~~ /
[
| 'x'
| '_' <!before [
        | $ 
        | '_' <?before $> 
        | '_' <?before ['_' <?before $>]>
        | '_' <?before ['_' <?before ['_' <?before $>]>]>
        # ...
    ]>
]+
/;
```

Is there a way to construct the rest of the pattern implied by the `...`?

Comment: Probably the easiest way to avoid matching whitespace at the end of a string, but matching it everwhere else is to go about it a very different way:: `\s+ <!before $>` That matches all stretches of whitespace, so long as it doesn't come right before the end of a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> avoid matching whitespace at the end of a string while still matching whitespace in the middle of words

Per Brad's answer, and your comment on it, something like this:

```
/ \w+ % \s+ /
```

> what I'm looking for is a way to match arbitrarily long streams that end with a known pattern

Per @user0721090601's comment on your Q, and as a variant of @p6steve's answer, something like this:

```
/ \w+ % \s+ )> \s* $ /
```

[The `)>` capture marker](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#index-entry-regex_%3C(_)%3E-Capture_markers:_%3C(_)%3E) marks where capture is to end.

You can use arbitrary patterns on the left and right of that marker.

> an infinite family of `<!before>` patterns

Generalizing to an infinite family of patterns of any type, whether they are [zero-width](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Zero-width_assertions) or not, the most natural solution in a regex is iteration using any of the standard [quantifiers](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Quantifiers) that are open ended. For example, `\s+` for one or more whitespace characters.<sup>**[1] [2]**</sup>

> Is there a way to construct the rest of the pattern implied by the `...`?

I'll generalize that to "Is there a way in a Raku regex to match some arbitrary pattern that could in theory be recognized by a computer program?"

**The answer is always "Yes"**:

- While Raku rules/regexes might look like traditional regexes they are in fact arbitrary functions embedded in an arbitrary program over which you ultimately have full control.
- Rules have arbitrary read access to capture state.<sup>**[3]**</sup>
- Rules can do arbitrary turing complete computation.<sup>**[4]**</sup>
- A collection of rules/regexes can arbitrarily consume input and drive the parse/match state, i.e. can implement any parser.

In short, if it can be matched/parsed by any program written in any programming language, it can be matched/parsed using Raku rules/regexes.

## Footnotes

<sup>**[1]**</sup> If you use an open ended quantifier you do need to make sure that each match iteration/recursion either consumes at least one character, or fails, so that you avoid an infinite loop. For example, the `*` quantifier will succeed even if the pattern it qualifies does not match, so be careful that that won't lead to an infinite loop.

<sup>**[2]**</sup> Given the way you wrote your example, perhaps you are curious about *recursion* rather than iteration. Suffice to say, it's easy to do that too.<sup>**[1]**</sup>

<sup>**[3]**</sup> In Raku rules, captures form a hierarchy. There are two special variables that track the capture state of two key levels of this hierarchy:

- [`$¢`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Match#index-entry-$%C2%A2) is the capture state of the innermost enclosing *overall* capture. Think of it as something analogous to a return value being constructed by the current function call in a stack of function calls.
- [`$/`](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/$$SOLIDUS) is the capture state of the innermost enclosing capture. Think of it as something analogous to a value being constructed by a particular block of code inside a function.

For example:

```
'123' ~~ / 1* ( 2* { print "$¢ $/" } ) 3* { print "$¢ $/" } / ; # 1 2123 123
```

- The overall `/ ... /` is analogous to an ordinary function call. The first `1` and first `123` of the output show what has been captured by that overall regex.
- The `( ... )` sets up an inner capture for a part of the regex. The `2* { print "$¢ $/" }` within it is analogous to a block of code. The `2` shows what it has captured.
- The final `123` shows that, at the top level of the regex, `$/` and `$¢` have the same value.

<sup>**[4]**</sup> For example, the code in footnote 3 above includes arbitrary code inside the `{ ... }` blocks. More generally:

- Rules can be invoked recursively;
- Rules can have full signatures and pass arguments;
- Rules can contain arbitrary code;
- Rules can use multiple dispatch semantics for resolution. Notably, this can include resolution based on longest match length.

Answer (score 6):

It is a little difficult to discern what you are asking for.

---

You could be looking for something as simple as this:

```raku
say 'x_x___x________' ~~ / 'x'+ % '_' ** 1..3 /
# ｢x_x___x｣
```

or

```raku
say 'x_x___x________' ~~ / 'x'+ % '_' ** 1..2 /
# ｢x_x｣
```

or

```raku
say 'x_x___x________' ~~ / 'x'+ % '_'+ /
# ｢x_x___x｣
```

Comment: I see @brad has (?) answered your actual question - here is the link to Modified Quantifier for Separators in the doc [https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Modified_quantifier:_%,_%%]

Comment: That's essentially the solution I settled on: `/ ['x'+]+ % '_'+ /`. However I think ultimately what I'm looking for a is a way to match arbitrarily long streams that end with a known pattern. I will try to clarify the question a bit.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using a [Capture](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Capturing)..., thusly:

```
'x_x___x________' ~~ /(.*?) _* $/; 
say $0;     #｢x_x___x｣
```

(The ? modifier makes the * 'non-greedy'.)
Please let me know if I have missed the point!

Comment: or, more compactly, ```say ('x_x___x________' ~~ /(.*?) _* $/)[0];```

Answer (score 1):

I’m wondering if Raku’s `trim()` routines might suit your purpose, for example: `.trim`, `.trim-trailing` or even `.trim-leading`. In the Raku REPL:

```perl6
> say 'x x  x   ' ~~ m:g/ 'x'+  \s* /;    
(｢x ｣ ｢x  ｣ ｢x   ｣)    

> say 'x x  x   '.trim-trailing ~~ m:g/ 'x'+  \s* /;    
(｢x ｣ ｢x  ｣ ｢x｣)
```

HTH.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/trim https://docs.raku.org/routine/trim-trailing https://docs.raku.org/routine/trim-leading